# GMail messages show wrong date after import

Tags: date, import, gmail

I have created a **Google Apps** account and then important my old email messages from my own IMAP-based mail server. For that purpose I used imapsync.
There is some mails which show up **fine** when viewed in **Thunderbird** -- interestingly enough as well on the old IMAP server **as on GMail**. They correctly have the date of original sending at **2nd of December 2008**. When viewing the full mail source ("original message") from GMail web interface, its **headers** read (XXX for anonymization in some places):

```
X-Account-Key: account6
X-UIDL: 10f6988675937085b6eXXX
X-Mozilla-Keys:                                                                                 
Return-Path: <XXX@t-online.de>
X-Flags: 0000
Delivered-To: GMX delivery to XXX@gmx.de
Received: (qmail invoked by alias); 02 Dec 2008 09:16:48 -0000
Received: from mailout09.t-online.de (EHLO mailout09.t-online.de) [194.25.134.84]
  by mx0.gmx.net (mx086) with SMTP; 02 Dec 2008 10:16:48 +0100
Received: from fwd02.aul.t-online.de 
by mailout09.sul.t-online.de with smtp 
id 1L7RN9-XXX; Tue, 02 Dec 2008 10:16:47 +0100
Received: from localhost (Tti8HrZYYh01uPSGlzL36WA4trfZ2XXX@[172.20.101.250]) by fwd02.aul.t-online.de
with esmtp id 1L7RMr-XXX; Tue, 2 Dec 2008 10:16:29 +0100
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: from 77.185.232.243:1675 by cmpweb16.aul.t-online.de with HTTP/1.1
 (Kommunikationscenter V9-2-23 on API V3-3-19)
Date: Tue, 02 Dec 2008 10:16:29 +0100
Reply-To: "XXX@t-online.de" <XXX@t-online.de>
To: XXX@gmx.de
X-Priority: 3
X-UMS: email
X-Mailer: TOI Kommunikationscenter V9-2-23
Subject: XXX
From: "XXX@t-online.de" <XXX@t-online.de>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="=_71bfbbb1eca6e77241917c40d55c1078"
Message-ID: <1L7RMr-XXX@fwd02.aul.t-online.de>
X-ID: Tti8HrZYYh01uPSGlzL36WA4trfZ2Ib9MXXX@t-dialin.net
X-TOI-MSGID: 6a3e3035-aa28-XXX
X-GMX-Antivirus: 0 (no virus found)
X-GMX-Antispam: 0 (Mail was not recognized as spam)
X-GMX-UID: GcoGeJ9WIyd1gjzXXX
```

But in the overview lists in the web interface it shows as dated **7th of October 2011**. This date might be the date of a previeous import (to my own IMAP server).

But I have no idea where Google takes that date from and how I can change this date to the date the message was really sent. Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue here, while syncing with imapsync. Was there any solution back then ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue now - unbelievably, six years later! Was there any fixes to this?

Answer (score 6):

I found this worked for me -

1. Copy all mails via IMAP from GMail to a local/different account folder
2. Now delete all mails from GMail using their Web interface
3. Empty the GMail trash
4. Copy all mails back from local/different account to GMail

Source - http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/0PU1gQuXNi8/HGu6GRigerMJ